# Why am I unable to make this conversion?

Tags: c++, io

I have the following piece of code for reading an input file and converting that input into an integer. It worked for some inputs but it isn't work anymore and that has been confusing me. (C++)

```
ifstream inputfile;

inputfile.open("inputfile.txt"); //openfile and read
string m; //fileforstringinput
getline(inputfile, m); //importing input information
long int s = atol(m.c_str());   //conversion to integer
inputfile.close(); //close file
cout << s;
```

When using this for small numbers it was fine. I tried the number from Project Euler problem 3 (600851475143)

and that failed to convert.

Does this exceed the size of long integers

Comment: Incidentally, why could you not just look up the size of long integers yourself?  This is extremely easy to find out.

Comment: If you intend to go on with the Euler problems you should get ready to work with long numbers anyway, since there are definitely problems that exceed any integer range.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does. According to the [<climits>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) header, the maximum value for long is **2147483647** (2^32/2 - 1).

You might try a 64-bit integer type (maximum 9223372036854775807), such as

- long long
- __int64
- int64_t

The best choice will probably depend somewhat on your compiler and architecture. Some searching online might be required to find which type is correct for your setup.

**Edit:** 
I originally suggested `double` as an alternative to `long long`, but *Brian* in the comments points out that it's probably a poor idea for prime factorization, which is inherently a whole-number operation. So strike that from the record and stick with something that models integers.

Comment: I recommend against using a double for prime factorization problems.  A `long long` should work fine for the specific problem the OP references.  On some compilers, you may need to use `__int64` instead.  I don't think either of those types are standard, if that is a concern.

Comment: This is completely dependent on the architecture (for example, in 64bit linux `long` is 64bits). If you need the range of a type in your platform, use the `<climits>` or `std::numeric_limits<>` template on your particular platform.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this exceed the size of long integers

Yes. A long integer is (usually) 4 bytes.  It can only store values between -2,147,483,647 and 2,147,483,647.

Comment: This is platform dependent, `long` can be 8 bytes in some architectures (in particular they **are** in 64bit linux)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, thanks, I qualified the answer slightly.